# How do I stop Uri root being changed?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to run this:

```
string webRoot = "http://www.dev/api";
string apiRoot = "http://api.dev";
string path = "/verify";
Uri root = (Settings.IsWebRoot) ? new Uri(webRoot) : new Uri(apiRoot);
Uri actualUri = new Uri(root, path);
```

However, `actualUri` is not `http://www.dev/api/verify` (which is what I'm expecting) but `http://www.dev/verify`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a little more flexible option you can use `UriBuilder`:

```
string webRoot = "http://www.dev/api";
string apiRoot = "http://api.dev";
string path = "/verify";
Uri root = (true) ? new Uri(webRoot) : new Uri(apiRoot);

UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(root);
builder.Path += path;

Uri actualUri = builder.Uri;
```

Comment: Do I still need to omit the starting slash (so that it's relative, not absolute) if I use the UriBuilder?

Comment: @PiersKarsenbarg Not in this case.

Comment: Note that if both webRoot and path do *not* end with slash  - it will give wrong results, so there is still some playing around with slashes.

Answer (score 2):

It's not very intuitive, but you need to:

1. End your `webRoot` with a slash.
2. Do *not* start your `path` with a slash (otherwise it will think it's absolute, not relative).

So the following will work fine:

```
string webRoot = "http://www.dev/api/";
string apiRoot = "http://api.dev/";
string path = "verify/";
Uri root = (true) ? new Uri(webRoot) : new Uri(apiRoot);
Uri actualUri = new Uri(root, path);
```